# Divisor Function of Sums in Fractions

Tags: summation, divisibility, natural-numbers

I have a question that I've been working on for a while now.  It says, "Let $A=\{0,1,2,\dots,2018\}$.  Prove that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists\{a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{2018}\}\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, $$(a_0<a_1<\dots<a_{2018})\wedge\frac{(\sum^{2018}_{k=0}a_k)div2019}{n+\sum^{2018}_{k=0}(a_kdiv2019)}=1."$$ I have no clue which $a_k$ to construct, and how they'll operate in that nasty fraction.  I have been trying to find an upper bound for $a_{2018}$ and working from there, but I seem to be getting nowhere.  I also tried setting the numerator equal to the denominator (since the fraction is equal to one) and working from there, but again, I didn't get very far.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the source of the problem? The use of numbers such as 2018 makes it look like an exam or contest question.

Comment: The source of the problem is a problem set.  I've been working on this question for forever now.  It's the only one that I haven't gotten yet

Comment: I've been trying to find what I can do with $a_{2018}$, since $\sum^n_{i=0}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, but I haven't gotten very far.

Comment: What does $(div2019)$ mean?  The last fraction is not a sentence, so how can it be part of a conjunction?

Comment: $a div 2019$ means that $a=2019q+r$ for some unique $q$ and $r$, and $div$ is the $q$; it's part of the division theorem.  For example, for $4 div2$, we know that 2 divides 4 twice, so the answer is $q=2$.

Comment: OK for div, but I still don't know how to have a fraction and something.  Is the fraction supposed to be equal to something?

Comment: You have to find some $a_0,...,a_{2018}$ such that the fraction is equal to one.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice my typo that the fraction was supposed to equal one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own question:   Choose $a_k=2019k+n$.  Then, in the nemerator, we have that $$\left(\sum^{2018}_{k=0}a_k\right)div2019=\left(\sum^{2018}_{k=0}(2019k+n)\right)div2019 =\sum^{2018}_{k=0}k+n.$$  In the denominator, we get $$n+\sum^{2018}_{k=0}(a_kdiv2019)=n+\sum^{2018}_{k=0}\big((2019k+n)div2019\big)=n+\sum^{2018}_{k=0}k.$$  It's now easy to see that the ratio between the numerator and denominator is $1$.